# comprobar la ortografía de un texto

Tags: python

necesito verificar la ortografía de un texto "con mi propio diccionario, ya que tengo palabras (creadas) en big.txt

este es el codigo

```
import re
from collections import Counter 
 
def h(x): 
    def words(text): return re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower()) 
 
    WORDS = Counter(words(open('big.txt').read())) 
 
    def P(word, N=sum(WORDS.values())):  
        "Probability of word." 
        return WORDS[word] / N 
 
    def correction(word):  
        "Most probable spelling correction for word." 
        return max(candidates(word), key=P) 
 
    def candidates(word):  
        "Generate possible spelling corrections for word." 
        return (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word]) 
 
    def known(words):  
        "The subset of words that appear in the dictionary of WORDS." 
        return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS) 
 
    def edits1(word): 
        "All edits that are one edit away from word." 
        letters    = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
        splits     = [(word[:i], word[i:])    for i in range(len(word) + 1)] 
        deletes    = [L + R[1:]               for L, R in splits if R] 
        transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R)>1] 
        replaces   = [L + c + R[1:]           for L, R in splits if R for c in letters] 
        inserts    = [L + c + R               for L, R in splits for c in letters] 
        return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts) 
 
    def edits2(word):  
        "All edits that are two edits away from word." 
        return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1)) 
 
    return correction(x) 
h('alivi')
```

mi problema ese codigo analiza solo palabras, para verificar un texto lo que hice fue que puse un  "for" para recorrer el texto, la cuestión es que es demasiado demorado para un texto de unas 100 líneas tarda mas o menos 20 minutos.

el codigo para verificar un texto con el for es este:

ese z_0 es un ejemplo del texto a verificar

```
z_0="mantenimientos descripcion hola" 
z_1=z_0.split()   
ff=[] 
ff.clear 
for z_2 in z_1: 
    ff.append(h(z_2)) 
fff=" ".join(ff) 
fff
```

alguien me podría decir como puedo crear un corrector de ortografía pero que lo haga con mi propio diccionario.

Comment: ¿Llamas a `h(x)` por cada palabra del texto o por el texto completo? Porque estás cargando y parseando el diccionario en cada llamada de `h`. Probe con palabras sueltas y funciona, pero con frases falla.

Comment: Bienvenido a SO **en español**!  Por favor, traduce tu pregunta. Ahora mismo puede ser cerrada por incumplimiento de la norma que nos obliga a todos a escribir en español en este sitio.

Comment: @CandidMoe exacto el código funciona es por palabras, para verificar si una frase esta escrita correctamente, convierto esa frase a una lista y luego con un for verificar palabra por palabra y luego las uno la corrección con un " ".join()   algo mas o menos asi              `z_0="mantenimientos descripcion hola" 
z_1=z_0.split()   
ff=[] 
ff.clear 
for z_2 in z_1: 
    ff.append(h(z_2)) 
fff=" ".join(ff) 
fff`

Comment: @CandidMoe hice un cambio en la pregunta, allí añado el ciclo for que te comente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una cantidad de ineficiencias en el código.

**Lees múltiples veces el diccionario**

La función `h` carga el `Counter` cada vez que lo llamas, cientos, miles de veces.

Solución: leer el diccionario sólo una vez al cargar el módulo.

**Lees todo el diccionario de una sola vez**

Es un diccionario grande y lo lees completo a memoria antes de formar el `Counter`. Ineficiente uso de la memoria.

Solución: leer el diccionario línea por línea.

**Computas `N` en cada llamada a la función `P`**

Como el argumento de la función `P` incluye una expresión para el valor por default, está expresión es computada cada vez que llamas a `P`:

```
sum(WORDS.values())
```

Solución: Computar `N` luego de cargar `WORDS`.

**Otros**

Usa expresiones regulares precompiladas, lo que acelera las operaciones de búsqueda posterior.

**Demo**

```
import re
from collections import Counter
import time

comienzo = time.time()
WORDS = Counter()
patron = re.compile(r'\w+')
with open('quijote.txt', 'r') as diccionario:
    for text in diccionario:
        WORDS.update(patron.findall(text.lower()))
N=sum(WORDS.values())
fin = time.time()
print(f"Carga en {fin-comienzo} segundos")


def h(word):
    "Most probable spelling correction for word."
    candidates = (known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known(edits2(word)) or [word])
    return max(candidates, key=lambda word: WORDS[word] / N)

def known(words):
    "The subset of words that appear in the dictionary of WORDS."
    return set(w for w in words if w in WORDS)

def edits1(word):
    "All edits that are one edit away from word."
    letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    splits = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]
    deletes = [L + R[1:] for L, R in splits if R]
    transposes = [L + R[1] + R[0] + R[2:] for L, R in splits if len(R) > 1]
    replaces = [L + c + R[1:] for L, R in splits if R for c in letters]
    inserts = [L + c + R for L, R in splits for c in letters]
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)

def edits2(word):
    "All edits that are two edits away from word."
    return (e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1))

tests = """
Cancha jidalgo lansa hastillero, adxrga antigua"""

for palabra in tests.split():
    corr = h(palabra)
    if corr != palabra:
        print(f"{palabra}*{corr}")
```

produce:

```
Carga en 0.19675564765930176 segundos
Cancha*mancha
jidalgo*hidalgo
lansa*lanza
hastillero,*astillero
adxrga*adarga

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Inicialmente ca

Comment: quedo perfecto, eres el/la mejor....

Comment: Una pregunta, conoces algún corrector de ortografía para español en python? mi primera alternativa para lo que estoy haciendo era con un corrector de ortografia, pero fue muy complejo encontrar librerías, solo salían para ingles @Candid Moe